# How to access Network Drive files using azure app services

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, shared-directory

I'm looking for a way to access the files from a shared folder in the network via Azure app services without dedicated on-premise gateway, and we shouldn't use user's credential due to confidentiality we can't keep user details in code or app config.
If some one know the way please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is my answer useful to you, do you need further help?